# Brazilian Portuguese diacritic

Tags: ortografia

What diacritic can be used in the following letters? (e.g. ai: ái, âi, aí, etc.)

ae: ???
ai: ???
an: ???
ao, au: ???
ei, ey: ???
en, em: ???
eo: ???
ia, ya: ???
ie, ye: ???
in, im: ???
io: ???
ion: ???
iu: ???
ou: ???
oa: ???
oe: ???
oi: ???
on, om: ???
ua: ???
uai: ???
ue: ???
ui: ???
un, um: ???

Comment: You mean how each "word" should be in Portuguese Orthography?

Comment: @Schilive What I asked is what diacritic can be used in "???". (e.g. ai: ái, âi, aí, etc.)

Comment: Niconii, for example, "ãi" and "ûa" ain't used, but you can write them. Would "ãi" or "ûa" be included in your list? Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Schilive Only actually used combinations are allowed. "ãi" or "ûa" etc. is not.

Comment: @Niconii your question is too broad. It feels strange, too, and I get the feeling that this is a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); maybe you want to know about all the possible diacritics in vowels?

Comment: @ANeves thinks SE is evil I just want to know about all the possible diacritics in vowels :)

Comment: Wikipedia has a thorough section on that, in the article about Portuguese ortography: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_orthography#Diacritics Is this enough to answer the question you have?

Answer (score 1):

Podem ser usados:

- Acento agudo;
- Acento circunflexo;
- Acento grave, quando há crase;
- Cedilha;
- Til;
- Trema.

Você pode conferir mais sobre o assunto nesse link [https://radames.manosso.nom.br/linguagem/gramatica/grafologia/diacriticos-da-ortografia-brasileira/#:~:text=Colocadas%20essas%20raz%C3%B5es%2C%20vamos%20falar,%2C%20cedilha%2C%20til%20e%20trema](https://radames.manosso.nom.br/linguagem/gramatica/grafologia/diacriticos-da-ortografia-brasileira/#:%7E:text=Colocadas%20essas%20raz%C3%B5es%2C%20vamos%20falar,%2C%20cedilha%2C%20til%20e%20trema).

Comment: O autor pergunta só sobre vogais. Agrada-me imenso estar aí incluida a cedilha, mas foge ao âmbito da pergunta.